# How to test a SMPS output?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, current, dc, switch-mode-power-supply

Can we test output voltage and current of a 12V 30A DC switching power supply without any electric consumer (DC motor, LED strip, etc.)?

Comment: You can check it by directly connecting positive and negative terminal to digital multimeter.

Comment: The output voltage can be checked using a multimeter with the option DC voltage, as for the deliverable current you would need some type of load. In this case the simplest one being a resistor, with a minimum value of \$12V/30A = 400m\Omega\$. The resistor must be rated to a power bigger than \$400m\Omega\cdot30A^2=360W\$ if there is no other load sharing the current. There are many other tests, which are usually done by the manufacturer such as stability, maximum capacitive load etc.

Comment: It **depends on what you want to test**. What **can** you test when no load is connected? You cannot test the current as the current will always be **zero** when no load is connected. That leaves the **voltage**. There can be ripple on that voltage, also that can be tested. But to test the **current rating** you will need to make the current flow, without a load, that's not going to happen.